# How to reset the reference counter with bibtopic

Tags: bibtex, counters

Everything is in the title.
Let's suppose that there is n reference in the `books.bib` file, I would like the references in the second section to start at 1 and not at n+1 as produced by defaut. What is the name of the counter to reset ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{books.bib}
@Book{Knuth1969,
    Title                    = {{The Art of Computer Programming}},
    Author                   = {Donald Knuth},
    Year                     = {1969},
    Volume                   = {2. Seminumerical Algorithms}
}

@Book{Knuth1968,
    Title                    = {{The Art of Computer Programming}},
    Author                   = {Donald Knuth},
    Year                     = {1968},
    Volume                   = {1. Fundamental Algorithms}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{articles.bib}
@Article{Doe2018,
    Title                    = {My beautiful paper},
    Author                   = {John Doe},
    Journal                  = {Any Journal},
    Year                     = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{btSect}[unsrt]{books}
    \section{References from books}
    \btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}[unsrt]{articles}
    \section{References from articles}
    \btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make that compilable?

Comment: It will require to build 2 bibtex files. I can Try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the numbering of references for every section, you can use `bibtopic`'s option `sectcntreset`.

From the [`bibtopic` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) ('2.2 Package Options', page 7):

> `sectcntreset` Reset the numerical label for the bibliography items
>   for each bt-Sect environment to ‘1’. (The default is continuous
>   numbering.) **Note**: This makes only sense when having at most one
>   `\btPrintCited` command in all your btSect environments; otherwise,
>   the citation labels in the document won’t be unique any more! The bad
>   thing is that you will get **no warning** from LaTeX about
>   `multiply-defined labels` in this case – so please use this option
>   with care.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the manual until the end

Comment: @DRi: If this answers your question, consider to accept it and vote it up ... (I know which user gave the only vote yet ;-))